# Javascript async code only works when debugging

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm using a js library that returns a ticket used for authentication purposes, and it does that asynchronously.

```
$(function(){
    if(auth && typeof auth === 'object')
    {
        auth.getTicket(function (obj){
            if(obj.status != 'FAILED')
            {
                console.log("got ticket");
                ticket = obj.ticket;
                var ofrs = new Offers();
                var _offers = ofrs.getOffers(appId, ticket, localeCode, getSpaceId(), baseUrl);
                if(_offers.success == true)
                {
                    console.log("retrieved offers");
                    ofrs.populatePlacements(_offers.offers.news)
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("error retrieving offers " + _offers.errorMessage);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("failed to get ticket");
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("error accessing auth object");
    }

});
```

This code works when debugging in chrome, eventually the callback passed as a parameter to `getTicket` fires and everything works. But if I'm not debugging then nothing happens. Why is this ?

Comment: is auth   Object get created dynamically ?  after the pageLoad is done ? then you might be calling getTicket on auth, before the object gets created completely . can you please check console for TypeError ?

Comment: the code snippet above is in a .js file that is included after another js file where the auth object is created. Also there's nothing in the console, no error, nor any log. It just does nothing.

Comment: and what about the console error when in failure ?

Comment: When it fails, nothing happens, no errors are logged.

Comment: Is `auth` set? Put a `console.log(auth)` before the `if`.